# Can't cancel request in interceptor

Tags: javascript, rxjs, nestjs

I'm trying to cancel request processing for requests longer than n seconds. For example, in this sample https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/01-cats-app

In `cats.controller.ts` replace

```js
@UseInterceptors(LoggingInterceptor, TransformInterceptor)
```

with

```js
@UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor, LoggingInterceptor, TransformInterceptor)
```

In `cats.controller.ts` replace

```js
  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }
```

with

```js
  @Get()
  async findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      if (i === 99999999) {
        return this.catsService.findAll();
      }
    }
  }
```

Add interceptor source:

```js
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(timeout(1));
  }
}
```

Request processing even after 1 ms and returns data. Logs:

```
Before...
After... 134ms
```

Interceptor's code from here: https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

What I did wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't cancel a `Promise`

Comment: I have a feeling this has to do with the order in which the interceptors are called. What happens when `TimeoutInterceptor` is last in the interceptors decorator?

Comment: Jay McDoniel, the same. Even if it is the only interceptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, figured out what's going on. When using a for loop the way you are, you're technically not moving onto the next part of the execution context, so the timeout pipe isn't starting to take effect yet. For the timeout operator to start, the `AppService`'s method has to be called to allow the callstack to keep moving on. You can return an asynchronous function and have the observable work with its timeout against how long the async function works, but a for loop in general is synchronous, which is where the erroneous functionality is coming in. If you want, try adding

```
function asyncTimeout(time: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), time);
  });
}
```

this function to your server and then calling `await asyncTimeout(5000)`.

You can use this for your `AppService`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

function asyncTimeout(time: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), time);
  });
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('In service');
    await asyncTimeout(5000);
    console.log('Returning after waiting');
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

And this for your `AppController`

```
import { Controller, Get, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { TimeoutInterceptor } from './timeout.interceptor';

@Controller()
@UseInterceptors(TimeoutInterceptor)
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('In controller');
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

and this as your `TimeoutInterceptor`

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    console.log('In interceptor');
    return next.handle().pipe(tap(() => console.log('In tap of return interceptor')), timeout(1));
  }
}
```

If you make a call off to `http://localhost:3000` you'll see the timeout happen almost instantaneously, and you'll see the log:

```sh
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:40 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:40 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +11ms
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:40 AM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +4ms
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:40 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +2ms
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:40 AM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
In interceptor
In controller
In service
[Nest] 10529   - 12/23/2019, 8:07:48 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] Timeout has occurred +7955ms
Returning after waiting
```

But in the HTTP response you will find

```sh
▶ curl http://localhost:3000
{"statusCode":500,"message":"Internal server error"}%
```

This is because you can't cancel the promise, so it will have to still finish its execution. You can however disregard the return of the promise, as you've already sent a response back to the client saying the request took too long.

[Here's a link to the repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-timeout-sample)